# ASP.Net MVC 2 editor templates

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

Can you recommend any good open source editor/display templates (mostly editor), preferably utilising jQuery.

Like AutoComplete, datePicker, color picker, multi-select, grids, trees etc.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

I am using [YUI 2](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/2/) to build my views in ASP.NET MVC project.
It can cover your requirement although it's not based on JQuery.